# I want to change the value of my input field based the value of my dropdown. But both should have different values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to change the value of my input field based the value of my dropdown. But both should have different values.

I want to have 2 different values like the dropdown value should be "Chenai - Pondicherry" and the input value must be 2000

i tried somethin like this but it's not workin. can anyone help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#price").live("change", function() {
 if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Pondicherry") { 
  $("#price").val("200");   
  } 
  else if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Thirupathi"){      
     $("#price").val("201"); 
  }else ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Kerala"){ 
      $("#price").val("202"); 
  }
  });
```

```html
 <input id="price" type="text" name="cuscharge" placeholder="price" readonly>

   <select id="options" name="tname"> 
    <option value="">Select Trip</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Pondicherry">Chenai - Pondicherry</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Thirupathi">Chenai - Thirupathi</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Kerala">Chenai - Kerala</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: As per the docs, the `.live` method is deprecated. The code seems proper though. Could you check using `.on` method?

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not a proper problem description and tells us nothing of value

Comment: the console tells u that u have syntax errors hence its aint working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed some errors and its working fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#options").change(function() {
        if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Pondicherry") { 
            $("#price").val("200");   
        } 
        else if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Thirupathi"){      
          $("#price").val("201");   
        }
        else if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Kerala"){ 
          $("#price").val("202");   
        }
        else
        {
          $("#price").val("Select Price");
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="price" type="text" name="cuscharge" placeholder="price" readonly value="">

<select id="options" name="tname"> 
    <option value="">Select Trip</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Pondicherry">Chenai - Pondicherry</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Thirupathi">Chenai - Thirupathi</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Kerala">Chenai - Kerala</option>
</select>
```

Comment: one thing you might need to edit is when the use select the blank option again, you also need to remove the price from the text box

Comment: Thanks Man it works fine now... Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

set values in html then change event assign to textbox

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#options").change(function() {
     $('#price').val($(this).val());
      });
    });
```

```html
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<input id="price" type="text" name="cuscharge" placeholder="price" readonly>
    
    <select id="options" name="tname"> 
     <option value="">Select Trip</option> 
     <option value="2000">Chenai - Pondicherry</option> 
     <option value="1000">Chenai - Thirupathi</option> 
     <option value="3000">Chenai - Kerala</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I want the value to be different from the dropdown value...  The above comment is what i was looking for. But thanks anyway man, appriciate your help.

Comment: @SubuHunter how is this different from other answers?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile well actually you've assigned 2000 as the value for the first dropdown option.. Actually i need  the text as the value itself, that's the difference

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#options").on("change",function() {
    if ($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Pondicherry"){ 
  $("#price").val("200");
        } 
    else if($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Thirupathi"){      
      $("#price").val("201"); 
     }
    else if($("#options").val() == "Chenai - Kerala"){ 
        $("#price").val("202"); 
     }
    else{
       $("#price").val(""); 
        }
  });
 });
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price" type="text" name="cuscharge" placeholder="price" readonly>

     <select id="options" name="tname"> 
    <option value="">Select Trip</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Pondicherry">Chenai - Pondicherry</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Thirupathi">Chenai - Thirupathi</option> 
    <option value="Chenai - Kerala">Chenai - Kerala</option>
   </select>
```

Add jquery library there is on change method in jquery,check if else loop also it is worng at else part.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#options").on("change", function() {
 var opt_val = $("#options").val();
 if (opt_val == "Chenai - Pondicherry") { 
  $("#price").val("200");   
  } 
  else if (opt_val == "Chenai - Thirupathi"){      
     $("#price").val("201"); 
  }else if(opt_val == "Chenai - Kerala"){ 
      $("#price").val("202"); 
  }
 });
  });
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input id="price" type="text" name="cuscharge" placeholder="price" readonly>
<select id="options" name="tname"> 
<option value="">Select Trip</option> 
<option value="Chenai - Pondicherry">Chenai - Pondicherry</option> 
<option value="Chenai - Thirupathi">Chenai - Thirupathi</option> 
<option value="Chenai - Kerala">Chenai - Kerala</option>
</select>
```